# How can I uniformly randomly rotate a Vector2 between 0 and 360 degrees?

Tags: java, vector

I have a `Vector2`:

```
Vector2 v = new Vector2(1,0);
```

How can I randomly rotate this vector (about (0,0)), with a uniform distribution in the range [0,360) degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To randomly rotate a vector `v`, counter clockwise:

```
Vector2 v = new Vector2( 1,0 );

Random rnd = new Random();
double rotationAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI * rnd.nextDouble();

Vector2 vRotated = new Vector2( 
   (v.x)*Math.cos(rotationAngle) + (v.y)*Math.sin(rotationAngle),
   (v.y)*Math.cos(rotationAngle) - (v.x)*Math.sin(rotationAngle)
);
```

The transformation mathematics comes from [here](http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/transform/rot.html)